# Запустить интерпретатор KevinScript

Tags: python

Привет!Скачал интерпретатор KevinScript на Питон.Там пакетная структура.Автор говорит что нужно запустить REPL так:

```
You can experiment with KS right away by using the REPL. Execute `src/ks.py` with no arguments.
C:\programming\Github projects\KevinScript>src\ks.py
    >>> print("Hello, world!")
    ...
    Hello, world!
```

Но там нет файла ks.py.В setup.py написано

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='KevinScript',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'kevinscript=ks:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

В **init** есть код REPL и функция main.
В **main** вызывает main функцию.Пытаюсь из (.) запустить так:

```
>python ks/__main__.py
Но выходит ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ks/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ks import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ks' 



D:.(D:\Python_code\LRParserFromGitHub\KevinScript)
|   .gitignore
|   README.md
|   setup.cfg
|   setup.py
|
|
+---ks
|   |   eval_ast.py
|   |   kobjects.py
|   |   language.txt
|   |   native_builtin_initialization.k
|   |   tokens.txt
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   __main__.py
|   |
|   +---parser
|   |       ast.py
|   |       followset.py
|   |       lex.py
|   |       LRParser.py
|   |       overview.txt
|   |       parserExceptions.py
|   |       parseRules.py
|   |       prettyprint.py
|   |       primitives.py
|   |       SLRtable.py
|   |       table.py
|   |       util.py
|   |       __init__.py
|   |
|   \---__pycache__
|           __main__.cpython-36.pyc
|
+---samples
|       hello_world.k
|       prime_detector.k
|
\---tests
        test.py
```

Comment: Не ясно как запускать https://github.com/kms70847/KevinScript/issues/7

Comment: Пробуйте `python -m ks`

Comment: Спасибо!Так работает.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста (если это можно отнести к этой теме).Я сделал файл myOwnGram.py в папке parser,который использует функцию из util.py.Как запустить файл  myOwnGram.py из (.).Ведь должна сохраняться структура пакета.Может так >python -m ks myOwnGram.py?